# How to auto login multiple user accounts on windows 7 using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-2.0, user-accounts

I want to write a script in PowerShell that auto login for multiple user accounts on a Windows (e.g. Windows 7) so when system reboots,all user accounts must be auto logged in. I know that one user account can be auto logged in using PowerShell. Is this possible for multiple user accounts?

Comment: I don't think it is. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need to log multiple users in for?

Comment: i wanna run a program on behalf of each user account after auto login,what should i do?

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. What do you want to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: there are five user accounts on windows 7 and they all  are running a program.For some reasons i have to restart the windows and then have to manually login all user accounts.I wanna auto login all those user accounts after resarting windows so that i dont have to manually login those accounts

Comment: i wanna automate this process using powershell